# Perfectomobile Initilazation Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to test a website on mobile using Perfectomobile in eclipse. I am getting the initialization error while run the code. It seems like an http request error. I am wondering if there is a proxy I can try with eclipse. I am able to go to this url directly on my browser.

Here is the code to initialize

```
public class MobileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String deviceID = "1F297702";
         \\Initializing
         MobileDriver driver = new MobileDriver();

         try {
             //code area
             driver.getDevice(deviceID);

             sleep(13000);
             MobileDeviceOpenOptions open = new MobileDeviceOpenOptions();
             driver.getDevice(deviceID).open(open);
```

And error Console

```
Error:
Run started
Starting Mobile Driver
12:16:55.103 [main] INFO  c.p.selenium.MobileDriver - Creating mobile driver
12:16:55.109 [main] INFO  c.p.selenium.MobileDriver - Starting execution
12:16:55.142 [main] INFO  c.p.httpclient.HttpClient - Processing request Request[_requestType=START_EXECUTION,_itemId=<null>,_parameters=[ParameterValue[_name=responseFormat,_value=xml]],_stringParameters=<null>,_encoding=<null>]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start play
    at com.perfectomobile.selenium.MobileDriver.initWithEclipseParams(MobileDriver.java:86)
    at com.perfectomobile.selenium.MobileDriver.<init>(MobileDriver.java:39)
    at MobileTest.main(MobileTest.java:41)

Caused by: com.perfectomobile.httpclient.HttpClientException: Error while processing HTTP request for URL in https  & username & password
    at com.perfectomobile.httpclient.HttpClient.sendTextRequest(HttpClient.java:195)
    at com.perfectomobile.httpclient.HttpClient.sendTextRequest(HttpClient.java:143)
    at com.perfectomobile.httpclient.HttpClient.sendValuesRequest(HttpClient.java:56)
    at com.perfectomobile.httpclient.execution.ExecutionsHttpClient.startPlay(ExecutionsHttpClient.java:217)
    at com.perfectomobile.selenium.MobileDriver.initWithEclipseParams(MobileDriver.java:76)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - perfecto mobile support proxy

see attached code:

```
// Setting up the proxy
          MobileProxy proxy = new MobileProxy("name",
                      8080, "XXX "XXX");
          DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
          MobileDriver connector = new MobileDriver(capabilities);
          System.out.println("Script started");
```

for more code exaples you can go to :
https://github.com/perfectomobile/examples

Comment: user@3423363, That is the one I am looking for. Thank you.